# Calculating the Conditional Probability Density Function

Tags: probability

Peter and Hans spend the random time $P$ and $H$ per week working. We know that $P\sim U(0,1)$. Now, for Hans we know that if Peters Time $P$ is given he needs the random time $H$

I want to calculate the mutual probability density function of $H$ and $P$.

For that we first note that we know: $P \sim U(0,1)$ and $H|P \sim U(0,P)$. So we get

$f_{H\mid P}(h\mid p)=\frac{1}{p}\,1_{(0,p)}(h) \tag{1}$

For the mutual probability density function we get

$f_{P,H}(p,h) = f_{P}(p)\, f_{H\mid P}(h\mid p)=\frac{1}{p}\, 1_{(0,p)}(h)\,1_{[0,1]}(p) \tag{2}$

whereas

$I_A(w):=\begin{cases} 1\quad w\in A\\ 0\quad w\in A^c\end{cases}$

Now while everything makes sense I'd love to have a more formal approach on getting (1). Sadly my course basically doesn't give a lot of details in the solutions and does a lot of "we just see it". But I'd like to derive it and not "see it". So can I derive (1) somehow more formally?

Comment: Why doesn't it follow directly from the density function of the uniform distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(H \leq h | P = p) = \mathbb{P}(\tilde{H} \leq h) = \frac{h}{p}1_{[0,p]}(h),
\end{align*}
with $\tilde{H} \sim U(0,p)$. Then:
\begin{align*}
f_{H | P = p}(h) = \frac{d}{dh}\mathbb{P}(H \leq h | P = p) = \frac{1}{p}1_{[0,p]}(h).
\end{align*}